# Variogram manual calculation

Tags: geospatial, gstat, covariogram

I have a question about variograms please.
In fact, I only have points with their Z(pi) values and the distances between them. (For example a point p1(z(p1),d(p1,p2), d(p1,p3),.., d(p1,pn)))
I want to estimate the variogram for those having a specific k distance between them.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually understood how to get that:

1. Forming multiple pairs {z(si),z(sj)} that have the same separation
   vectors h = si −sj and estimate correlation from them.
2. Calculating the Estimated value for each pair : **(Z(Si) - Z(Si + h))**
3. Calculating The probability of each pair : **P(Z(S=Si)- Z(S=Si + h))**
4. The the semi variance will be just : **1/2 var[(Z(si)- Z(si + h))]**